# High Contrast 'overflowing'

Tags: eclipse, windows, contrast

I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit and whenever I use a high contrast theme, it leaks out into Eclipse, making it look high contrast, too. Here's a pic with the issue i'm having https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm1Gh.png

I was wondering if I can somehow disable this "high contrast" mode eclipse seems to be getting in.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This response comes very late, but I have the same concern.  I have a love/hate relationship with high contrast mode. As I stare at a screen all day, I use it to get rid of as much pure white as possible.  However, some apps will abandon superior dark styles in High Contrast Mode, in order to be "accessible".  Eclipse is one of these.

My unfortunate solution is to start eclipse while in low contrast mode, then switch to high contrast mode.  Eclipse will say it needs to restart to apply high contrast settings, but you can cancel it, and it will keep its theme.

There are other strategies I use with other apps as well.  Dangit windows, couldn't you just keep the styling options you used to have?